# How apply a stylesheet a view speficied in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following problem. I have the view app/view/home/index.html.erb

```
<h1 id="title">Index</h1>
<table width="300">  
 <tr>
    <td class="title">Table Users</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Users' ,users_path %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="title">Table Provinces</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Provinces' ,provinces_path %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="title">Table BreakPoints</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'BreakPoints' ,break_points_path %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="title">Table Bus Companies</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Bus Companies' ,bus_companies_path %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="title">Table Seat Types</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Seat Types' ,seat_types_path %></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I have an stylesheet for the controller home   called  app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.sass

```
// Place all the styles related to the Home controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
td{
    text-align: left;
}
table{
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

The problem is that the ṕroperties css applied to this controller home as for example border-style-solid are applied  to the views the others controllers not only a the views the controller home as for example app/views/home/index.html.erb. All the tables of the application have border-style-solid and I want that only the view of  app/views/home/index.html.erb has border-style:solid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a class to the table in your home views and define the class in home.css. Something like

app/view/home/index.html.erb

```
<h1 id="title">Index</h1>
<table class="home-table" width="300">
```

app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.sass

```
// Place all the styles related to the Home controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
table.home-table td{
    text-align: left;
}
.home-table{
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vimsha. I'm sorry for the question. I thought that Rails could understand the separation between stylesheets for each controller